# Database of images and text

Tags: sql, database, image, text

### background:

I'm in the design phase of building an app.
I want the app to display text and images, the problem is that I will have A LOT of them. hundreds to thousands.
This is my largest app so far, and I am unsure on how to handle all the data.

### The question???????:

What would be the best way to store and access these images and text?
Would I use a formal database approach like SQL?
Or would it be better to navigate files/folders e.g. dropping all the files in res/drawable?

### potentially useful facts:

The database will be stored and accessed natively so it can be accessed off-line.
The user will not be adding to the database in anyway, only accessing the data.
the database will be updated every 6 months.
The application 'page' will display 1-5 images along with several blocks of text.

### Concept:

the app will be like a recipe app...the user will pick some parameters e.g. ingredients, type, diet.. then select a recipe. And then several images and blocks of text will be displayed showing and detailing the process of some recipe.

I apologize if this is repeated but I didn't see a specific answer for my purposes.

Answer (score 1):

The "Best" approach will depend on the functionality of the database server in question.

Generally, you should store the images "In" the database until that becomes a performance issue. Once you start storing images "Outside" of the database you will have to handle all the issue that are normally taken care of by the database. Disk space management, orphan records, file name conflicts, folder file limits, to name just a few. Depending on your situation these may be big issues or thay may be nothing to worry about.

I've seen several application where images (or attachements) were kept "Outside" the database, and in each case it was done poorly. There are just so many issues to handle, and most developers don't even think of half of them. In many cases the performance of storing the images "In" the databse was acceptable, but the developers decided against it because they just knew it would not perform well.

Comment: "Disk space management, orphan records, file name conflicts, folder file limits," none of these attributes apply as the data is static

Comment: The files have to be placed on the filing system at least once, that means disk space and folder file limits come into play. And all of those files need names. What are you going to call them? This is stuff that is already taken care of by the database itself.

Comment: Burns The disk space issue should be taken care of by the installer. This would be true BTW for both a file or DB based resources. The point I was trying to make was that the DB scenario is much more powerful for mutable data

Answer (score 0):

If your using SQL server 2008 the [Filestream](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc949109%28v=sql.100%29.aspx) data type is ideal for your case. It stores the binary files outside of the database but behaves as a normal field. Also you are able to read/write the files using a stream instead of getting/setting the whole file as a byte array (like when using `varbin(max)`)

If you don't have this functionality in your database, I would recommend storing the images outside of the DB

Answer (score 0):

Its probably a better idea to use a file based approach for deployed static resources.

At the very least because taking a dependency on file system is typically easier to manage then taking a dependency on a DB.

Also this line indicates some sort of non-web client

> The database will be stored and accessed natively so it can be accessed off-line."

This means if you go with the DB approach you'll have a couple of other interesting problems

**Deployment**

Depending on the platform deploying a DB can be a real bear depending on your target platform. What happens if they if already have the engine but its a different version.

**Resources**

Is your DB going to be client/server based (like MySQL/SQL Server etc)? If so then your app has to now manage the current state of its process.  If not then you'll be using a file-based db SQL Lite/MS Access, at which point I would question why using a static DB is worth doing at all.

One final note. There's nothing stopping your Content Production environment from using a DB. Its quite common for Content producers to maintain a database for their content that will you will later use to produce the files for publishing/deployment.